# Django query record with largest version in group

Tags: django

I have a very simple Django model which represents a versioned Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "version")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({f'v{self.version}' if self.version else 'DRAFT'})"
```

I can create some products in the database using the following script:

```
p1_v1, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="One", version=1)
p1_v2, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="One", version=2)
p1_v3, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="One", version=3)
p1_draft, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="One", version=None)

p2_v1, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="Two", version=1)
p2_v2, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="Two", version=2)

p3_draft, _ = Product.objects.get_or_create(name="Three", version=None)
```

I need to perform a query that returns the latest version of each Product (excluding Products with no version). That is, the target result is the following `Queryset`:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: One (v3)>, <Product: Two (v2)>]>
```

The following works with PostgreSQL but fails with SQLite:

```
Product.objects.exclude(version__isnull=True).order_by("name", "-version").distinct("name")
# <QuerySet [<Product: One (v3)>, <Product: Two (v2)>]>
```

I'm able to get the max version per name here but I'm not sure how to get the actual objects from the db:

```
Product.objects.values("name").annotate(max_code_version=Max("version"))
# <QuerySet [{'name': 'One', 'max_code_version': 3}, {'name': 'Two', 'max_code_version': 2}]>
```

How can I execute this query?

Comment: Did you try deleting `.values('name')` from the query?

Comment: @oz19 that doesn't work

Comment: @JohnnyMetz Why do you want to use `SQLite` here? You might already know but I would like to mention it again that passing a list of fields in `distinct` is a postgres specific behavior in django. Reference to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct): `On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply.`

Comment: @AKS I don't need to use SQLite. I'm exploring what options I have for this query and choosing the database based on that.

Comment: @JohnnyMetz If what you have posted is the only requirement here, `PostgreSQL` is the way to go. Because, any other way will have a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ease of use, you should change your ***annotation field name*** to **`version`** from `max_code_version`

```
import functools
import operator
from django.db.models import Max, Q

group_by_expression = Product.objects.values("name").annotate(version=Max("version"))
filter_qry = functools.reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**item) for item in group_by_expression])
qs = Product.objects.filter(filter_qry)
```

**Example**

```
In [7]: group_by_expression = Product.objects.values("name").annotate(version=Max("version"))                                                                                                                      

In [8]: filter_qry = functools.reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**item) for item in group_by_expression])                                                                                                                   

In [9]: qs = Product.objects.filter(filter_qry)                                                                                                                                                                    

In [10]: qs                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[10]: <QuerySet [<Product: One (v3)>, <Product: Three (DRAFT)>, <Product: Two (v2)>]>

In [11]: group_by_expression                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[11]: <QuerySet [{'name': 'One', 'version': 3}, {'name': 'Three', 'version': None}, {'name': 'Two', 'version': 2}]>
```